# Reducing Array inside of an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this Data Structure :

```
const data = [
```

{
id: 1,
urlName: 'balance-at-work',
offices: [
{
location: 'Sydney, Australia',
in_range: false
},
],
},
{
id: 2,
urlName: 'spring-development',
offices: [
{
location: 'Banbury, Oxfordshire',
in_range: true
},
],
},
{
id: 3,
urlName: 'talent-lab',
offices: [
{
location: 'MÃ©xico City, Mexico',
in_range: false
},
{
location: 'London, UK',
in_range: true
},
],
},
];

I want to reduce the offices array inside each object by using the great circle distance formula.

So far i have been able to calculate the great circle distance and add a `dist` key inside each office object. What i am having issue with, is a clean way to remove all the objects inside each offices array for each user when `dist` is greater than a given range.

Comment: And the problem is? `Array.prototype.filter()`, a simple `for` loop (iterate from the last to the first item) + `.splice()`, ...

Comment: Please give an example of input is this and output should be this. Its hard to comprehend the problem.

Comment: yes @ShravanDhar the output is the same but if the office didn't match the range than i should remove it. If the office array is empty then the whole parent object should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this might be something like the following (`is_office_in_range` is just a placeholder for however you determine whether an office should be included or not):

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    urlName: 'balance-at-work',
    offices: [
      {
        location: 'Sydney, Australia',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    urlName: 'spring-development',
    offices: [
      {
        location: 'Banbury, Oxfordshire, UK',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    urlName: 'talent-lab',
    offices: [
      {
        location: 'MÃ©xico City, Mexico',
      },
      {
        location: 'London, UK',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const is_office_in_range = (office) => office.location.endsWith('UK');

const res = data
  .map((company) => ({
    ...company,
    offices: company.offices.filter((office) => is_office_in_range(office))
  }))
  .filter((company) => company.offices.length);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Can you please share with me the way to insert in_range field ? is there a way to do it without nested loops ?

Comment: @AnthonyG.Helou You wouldn't necessarily need to insert the in_range field; in the office filter you could replace `office.in_range` with a function call to check whether the office is in range e.g. `is_office_in_range(office)`.